# How to write select statement in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I want to get only specific column details from ActiveRecord.
So I did run the following code.

```
accounts = self.accounts(:select => "id, name,account_number").order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => page_count, :per_page => per_page_count)
```

Whenever this line is getting executed its firing this following query

```
SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" INNER JOIN "super_account_accounts" ON "accounts"."id" = "super_account_accounts"."account_id" WHERE "super_account_accounts"."super_account_id" = 8 ORDER BY accounts.created_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Why it is getting all the column information when I have already specified few of the columns for which I want the info.

NOTE:-

Super account model has the following association with account

```
has_many :accounts, :through => :super_account_accounts, :dependent => :destroy
```

account model has the following association with super account

```
has_many :super_accounts, :through => :super_account_accounts
```

**EDIT 1**

So got it working by using the following

```
    accounts = self.accounts.select("id, name,account_number").order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => page_count, :per_page => per_page_count)
```

Lets say i want to fetch 10-11 columns.
after using the above query, when i tried to apply to_json method its only taking some of the columns into consideration while ignoring rest of the columns.

Any inputs on why such thing is happening with to_json method?
Am i missing something?

**EDIT2**
got the to_json thing working by writting the following code

```
account.to_json({ :only => [:id, :name, :account_number, :column4, :column5, :column8, :column9] })
```

Still Am not sure why we need to specify the column names inside to_json method as we are already getting that from the select query.very strange

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
accounts = self.accounts.select(:id, :name, :account_number).order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => page_count, :per_page => per_page_count)
```

Comment: tried this its throwing the following error:
wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..1) because select expects only single argument or so tried with 
 self.accounts.select("accounts.id, accounts.name, accounts.account_number").order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => page_count, :per_page => per_page_count)

Comment: when i add more than 3 columns and apply to_json it only converts some of the columns to json and ignores rest of the column

Comment: you want to select only these columns `id`, `name` and `account_number` from the table right ?

Comment: No i want to fetch probably 10-11 columns and want to apply to_json while returning from controller but the to_json method only  converting some of the columns to json and ignoring rest of the column

Answer (score 0):

Please use select correctly
it should be `select('id, name')`
then your query will be :

```
accounts = self.accounts.select('id,name,account_number').order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => page_count, :per_page => per_page_count)
```

Comment: after following sa77 answer and tweaking a bit here and there i tried with the above query and am getting expected result
when i add more than 3 columns and apply to_json it only converts some of the columns to json and ignores rest of the column

Comment: Hi any input on my 2nd query?

Answer (score 0):

```
accounts = self.accounts.select("id, name,account_number").order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => page_count, :per_page => per_page_count)
```

and for the to_json method

```
return {
  account.to_json({ :only => [:id, :name, :account_number, :column4, :column5, :column8, :column9] })
}
```

Comment: what are entries in account? I think you are looping  over accounts(where you are selecting particular attributes) and so in account while using to_json you are getting particular fields only